# Can't ping Hyper-V Arch Linux through internal network

Tags: linux, windows, networking, hyper-v

I have created a Hyper-V Virtual Machine running Arch Linux. I want to have two NIC's.

- The first NIC is an external nic for internet connection.
- The second NIC should be an internal nic - the reason is that if I change network I want to have a static ip address that works on my laptop regardless of the DHCP settings of the network.

I have created a virtual switch with internal as adapter. On my laptop (Win 10) I have set up as follows:

```
IP Address: 192.168.137.1
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: Blank
DNS 1: 192.168.137.1
DNS 2: Blank
```

My Virtual Machine (Arch Linux) has:

```
IP: 192.168.137.2
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.137.1
DNS: 192.168.137.1
```

Ping from HOST to GUEST does not work, GUEST to HOST does not work.

Any help/advice?

Comment: Running Ubuntu 16.10 does not give any problems :S

Comment: From the Arch Linux machine, are you able to ping the gateway (192.168.137.1) at all?

Comment: Nope, not able to ping from HOST <=!=> GUEST

Answer (score 0):

If `192.168.137.1` and `192.168.137.2` are visible interfaces on the same machine (eth0 and eth1 for instance), that [won't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178206/two-nics-in-the-same-subnet-need-to-set-up-routing)

If the are on separate kernel stacks, have a look at each interface using the `ip` command. Ensure the link is `state UP` on each interface.

```
# ip link sho eth1
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:38:41:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Next, `su/sudo` to root and run the `arping` command to/from each IP address (`/usr/sbin/arping 192.168.137.2`). You will probably need to install the utility. Devices on the same subnet will always reply to this if they are plugged in and there is no problem with physical cabling, hardware.  Even if ICMP is dropped on firewall, arping will succeed.

Also, make sure dhcp is disabled for the interface you have configured manually (static). Depending on what craziness your Linux distro is using for configuring the interface, this can be quite a chore for some.

if `arping` fails, you will need to do some investigation into the pieces between the IP address. Make sure the hypervisor knows the nic should be enabled on the virtual machine and is allowing access to it, virtual switch is configured correctly, etc. etc. Maybe remove some pieces in between and test again.